# sudo cat /dev/input/eventX shows nothing

Tags: 18.04, input-devices, embedded-system

Ubuntu 18.04,

in terminal when I do

```
sudo cat /dev/input/event0 or eventX
```

nothing shows up! what is wrong here?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340430/dev-input-what-exactly-is-this

Comment: this "sudo cat mouse0 | hexdump -C" shows nothing for me too, that is my question

Comment: Did you not read the answer there?

Comment: Now I see thanks!